# doing it the toolbar way instead of list view

Tags: java, android

```
lvRSS = (ListView)findViewById (R.id.lvRSS)
lvRSS.setOnItemClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
  public void onItemClick (AdpaterView<?>parent,View view, int position, 
  long id)
}
```

it will work on listview but i cant to mimic the same for toolbar

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setOnItemClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
      public void onItemClick (AdpaterView<?>parent,View view, int 
      position, long id)
    }
```

please help

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? Do you want to handle the click of navigation icon or some item in toolbar? Please provide screenshots if possible.

Comment: so whats your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toolbar does not contain the setOnItemClickListener () event. If you want to make the event click on Toolbar, try this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```